# How can I use java and maven to download, unzip and add to the compilation the proprietary jars inside a zip file

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have a maven multi-module project and one of the sub-modules requires proprietary libraries to compile, specifically I am downloading the latest version of [intellij-idea](/questions/tagged/intellij-idea) Community Edition in a [zip](/questions/tagged/zip) file from its official page.

My first approach was to download using a [travis-ci](/questions/tagged/travis-ci) script for linux and on windows using [appveyor](/questions/tagged/appveyor), but since I want to integrate it with [sonatype-deepshield](/questions/tagged/sonatype-deepshield) I must control the process **entirely from maven**.

The whole process should consist of:

- zip download
- zip decompression
- dependency registration in maven local repository (currently I don't do this since I use scope system and I don't know any other way)
- reference dependencies
- compilation

This is my pom so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.javapro</groupId>
        <artifactId>regextester-pom</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>regextester-idea</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>regextester Client for Idea</name>

    <properties>
        <!-- Plugin meta information -->
        <vendor.url>http://www.javapro.org</vendor.url>
        <vendor.email>myemail@gmail.com</vendor.email>
        <vendor.name>Ruslan López Carro - Java PRO</vendor.name>
        <!-- IntelliJ distribution related properties-->
        <intellij.version>13.0.2</intellij.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <ij.plugin>true</ij.plugin>
        <INTELLIJ_HOME>C:/Users/javatlacati/.IntelliJIdea2019.3/system/plugins-sandbox</INTELLIJ_HOME>
        <idea.systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib</idea.systemPath>
        <project.mainclass>org.javapro.regextester.MyToolWindowFactory</project.mainclass>
        <exec.java.bin>${java.home}/bin/java</exec.java.bin>
        <exec.debug.arg>-Ddebug=false</exec.debug.arg>
        <springloaded.javaagent>-Djavaagent=false</springloaded.javaagent>
        <dependency.plugin.version>2.3</dependency.plugin.version>
        <comipler.plugin.version>2.5.1</comipler.plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <exec.debug.arg>-Ddebug=false</exec.debug.arg>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>regextester-js</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--idea dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${idea.systemPath}/lib/util.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-core-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${idea.systemPath}/lib/platform-core-ui.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${idea.systemPath}/lib/openapi.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${idea.systemPath}/lib/platform-api.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${idea.systemPath}/lib/annotations.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <!--javafx-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jar</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                    <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                    <destFileName>springloaded.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <type>zip</type>
                    <classifier>webpages</classifier>
                    <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/org/javapro/regextester</outputDirectory>
                    <includes>*/**</includes>
                    <includeGroupIds>${project.groupId}</includeGroupIds>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- get all project dependencies -->
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>

                    <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>${project.mainclass}</mainClass>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <useUniqueVersions>false</useUniqueVersions>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>

                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>download-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-idea-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wget</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <url>https://www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases/com/jetbrains/intellij/idea/ideaIC/${env.VERSION}/ideaIC-${env.VERSION}.zip</url>
                            <unpack>true</unpack>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

<!--            <plugin>-->
<!--                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>-->
<!--                <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>-->
<!--                <version>2.0.0</version>-->
<!--                <executions>-->
<!--                    <execution>-->
<!--                        <id>downloadIC</id>-->
<!--                        <phase>validate</phase>-->
<!--                        <goals><goal>download-single</goal></goals>-->
<!--                        <configuration>-->
<!--                            <url>https://www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases/com/jetbrains/intellij/idea/ideaIC/${env.VERSION}/</url>-->
<!--                            <fromFile>ideaIC-${env.VERSION}.zip</fromFile>-->
<!--                            <toFile>${project.basedir}/lib/ideaIC-${env.VERSION}.zip</toFile>-->
<!--                        </configuration>-->
<!--                    </execution>-->
<!--                </executions>-->
<!--            </plugin>-->

<!--            <plugin>-->
<!--                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>-->
<!--                <version>1.8</version>-->
<!--                <executions>-->
<!--                    <execution>-->
<!--                        <id>prepare</id>-->
<!--                        <phase>validate</phase>-->
<!--                        <configuration>-->
<!--                            <tasks>-->
<!--                                <echo message="unzipping file ${project.basedir}/lib/ideaIC-${env.VERSION}.zip to ${project.basedir}/lib" />-->
<!--                                <unzip src="${project.basedir}/lib/ideaIC-${env.VERSION}.zip" dest="${project.basedir}/lib"/>-->
<!--                            </tasks>-->
<!--                        </configuration>-->
<!--                        <goals>-->
<!--                            <goal>run</goal>-->
<!--                        </goals>-->
<!--                    </execution>-->
<!--                </executions>-->
<!--            </plugin>-->
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

It works perfectly on Linux, but on Windows, it works only if the download was already in the maven cache or in the local repository, but [not in a clean installation](https://depshield.sonatype.org/error/javatlacati/regextester/-_8o227xM2lE789e1ybNfQ).

As you can appreciate I've tried with [download-maven-plugin](/questions/tagged/download-maven-plugin), [maven-antrun-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-antrun-plugin) and [wagon-maven-plugin](/questions/tagged/wagon-maven-plugin) without success.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fundamental problem with your approach is that dependencies are always resolved at the very beginning of the Maven run. So when you run

```
mvn clean install
```

Then *first* the dependencies are resolved and then subsequent steps are run. So if copy or resolve a dependency during the build, it cannot be found if it was not already there at the beginning.

So if you want to solve this problem with Maven, you need at least two separate Maven runs.

That said, I do not understand yet why you cannot construct a pipeline (I don't know travis-ci, but it is probably similar to Jenkins) that first unpacks and downloads the dependencies and then calls `mvn clean install`. But I do not know `sonatype-deepshield` and cannot judge on this.

Comment: As I said my approach works with only one run, but only on Linux, that's because of the plugin I'm using works in the phase generate sources that precede compilation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciktU.png The problem is that it doesn't work because windows doesn't have wget command to be run.

Comment: But dependency resolution happens before any of the phases are run. Maybe this works in some cases because `<scope>system</scope>` dependencies are not checked as thoroughly as other dependencies.